# Retarding the start of an animation. How?

Tags: rendering, animation, keyframes

I have been working on this low poly dragon awakening animation and all is going fine.

However, due to camera movement in the final render, I would like the animation of the dragon to start at around frame 100 and not at frame one in the final render where I have the Background ready.  I tried to move the whole dragon animation in the final render to 100 but it still starts at 1.

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: in the dopesheet move the keyframes for the animation you want to delay.

Comment: I just tried it but it is not working

Comment: Are you sure you move all keyframes?

Comment: I am pretty sure to have done it as you can see from the 3rd picture I uploaded.

Comment: I bet it is not working because the keyframe marked in red is not moving with the other keyframes.